# How to extract few cells from a Google Sheet and copy to another sheet using a single statement

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

using JavaScript to access google sheets via google API.

I am copying the entire content of a "google spreadsheet" "Parent sheet" into a two dimension array vaParent

```
  var ssParent = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Parent");
 var vaParent = ssParent.getRange(2, 1, ssParent.getLastRow(), ssParent.getLastColumn() ).getValues();
```

I am extracting 6 array elements

```
  var vaNewParent01 = vaParent[i].slice(3, 9);
```

Now, I would like to copy vaNewParent01 to a new google "spreadsheet" "company sheet"

```
  ssCompany.getRange( 2, 1 ).setValues( vaNewParent01 );
```

above code does not work??

I've found that vaNewParent01 is a single dimension array with 6 elements

however,  ssCompany.getRange( 2, 1 ).setValues( vaNewParent01
only works if vaNewParent01 is an array of array

question:
a/ how to extract few cells from a sheet and copy to another using a single statement.

thanks in advance for any help

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
arr is single dimension array

let vs = arr.map(e => [e]); //for a column;
let vs = [arr]; //for a row

Sheet.getRange(1,1,vs.length, vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
```

Comment: have also learned that the append command adds a new row at the end of the Google Sheets table; Sheet1.appendRow( vData1 ), vData1 is an array of values that matched the column for Sheet1

Comment: Yes, but it's quite a bit slower than using setValues()

Answer (score 2):

From your showing script, if your script is like the following script,

```
var ssParent = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Parent");
var vaParent = ssParent.getRange(2, 1, ssParent.getLastRow(), ssParent.getLastColumn()).getValues();
for (var i = 0; i < vaParent.length; i++) {
  var vaNewParent01 = vaParent[i].slice(3, 9);
  ssCompany.getRange(2, 1).setValues(vaNewParent01);
}
```

`vaNewParent01` is 1 dimensional array. In order to use `setValues(values)`, `values` is required to be 2 dimensional array. And about `ssCompany.getRange( 2, 1 ).setValues( vaNewParent01 );`, in this case, please include the numbers of rows and columns of the values you want to put. If my understanding of your situation is correct, I think that the reason for your issue is due to this.

About `how to extract few cells from a sheet and copy to another using a single statement.`, in this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script 1:

This script is modified from your showing script by guessing your tested script.

```js
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var ssParent = ss.getSheetByName("Parent");

var ssCompany = ss.getSheetByName("sample"); // Please set the destination sheet name.

var vaParent = ssParent.getRange(2, 1, ssParent.getLastRow(), ssParent.getLastColumn()).getValues();
var values = [];
for (var i = 0; i < vaParent.length; i++) {
  var vaNewParent01 = vaParent[i].slice(3, 9);
  values.push(vaNewParent01);
}
ssCompany.getRange(2, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
```

#### Sample script 2:

As other sample script, how about the following script? In this sample script, `copyTo` of Class Range is used. From your showing script, I thought that you wanted to copy the values from `D2:I` of the source sheet to `A2` of the destination sheet.

```js
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var ssParent = ss.getSheetByName("Parent");

var ssCompany = ss.getSheetByName("sample"); // Please set the destination sheet name.

var src = ssParent.getRange("D2:I" + ssParent.getLastRow());
src.copyTo(ssCompany.getRange(2, 1), { contentsOnly: true });
```

#### References:

- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [copyTo(destination, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination,-options)

Comment: thanks for the previous reply

the exercise has evolved

I have two "google spreadsheet "sheets, parent and company s

Comment: @Trajano Roberto Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: function insertCompany( vaParent, ssCompany, vaCompany, vCompanyId, vMarketId, vClassId, i, j  ) { 

  vaCompany.push(vCompanyId);

  vaCompany.push(vMarketId);  

  vaCompany.push(vClassId);

  var vaNewParent = vaParent[i].slice(3,9);

  vaCompany.push( vaNewParent )


above code not working??
any idea why?

Comment: @Trajano Roberto About your new question of `function insertCompany( vaParent, ssCompany, vaCompany, vCompanyId, vMarketId, vClassId, i, j ) { vaCompany.push(vCompanyId); vaCompany.push(vMarketId); vaCompany.push(vClassId); var vaNewParent = vaParent[i].slice(3,9); vaCompany.push( vaNewParent ) above code not working?? any idea why?`, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand what you want to do in your new question. But, I would like to support you. So, can I ask you about the detail of your new question? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: thank you for the comment, the question has been answered; cheers